# LSI Model fails to load the model

Tags: scikit-learn, gensim, latent-semantic-indexing

I have a LSI model stored and the model is getting stored as model.pkl and model.pkl.projection.

However, when I try to load the model the loading is failing because its trying to look for projection file with .npy

```
loading LsiModel object from /var/app/data/lsi_model.pkl.projection
loading u from /var/app/data/lsi_model.pkl.projection.u.npy with mmap=r
failed to load projection from /var/app/data/lsi_model.pkl.projection: 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'/var/app/data/lsi_model.pkl.projection.u.npy'
```

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: How about just changing the extension so that the file name ends with '.npy'?

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: Isn't the name of the file `u.npy`? in directory " /var/app/data/lsi_model.pkl.projection"? Then you should ensure you use `os.path.join` to get proper path:  "/var/app/data/lsi_model.pkl.projection/u.npy" instead of path leading to file `projection.u.npy` in directory  /var/app/data/lsi_model.pkl. Or maybe your file is /var/app/dasta/lsi_model.pkl?

Comment: Either way, it is likely to be path-related.